# What is the relationship with power, justice, and respect?

Tags: measurement

King has power
King are respected (people bow to them)
Just king are respected more than unjust king

Just laws are respected more than unjust laws.

What are the relationship of that?

Is respect merely beliefs, or perceptions of power and justice?

Is there a mathematical relationship?

Do people obey those who they respect more?

Comment: I mean this seems to be intuitively obvious for most people. However, I am looking for some "rational" studies that see the relationship. For example, what "respect" means is quite vague. So perhaps there is some study on it?